# How to return the pivot after attaching a model to Another?

Tags: laravel

I want to get the pivot inserted when doing this :

```
App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

In the model :

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

I would like to be able to do this :

```
 $pivot = App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you should add `withPivot` in your method relations

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('expires', 'column2');
}
```

And after that you can call it like this:

```php
$user = App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
$pivot = $user->pivot-> expires;
```

Comment: `$user->pivot->expires `return null